# How to return an API response AND fail the program at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

I have an Azure Function acting as an API endpoint and in case of an exception, I need a way of both returning a 500 error to the user and exiting the program with an error code.

```
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
try:
    <do the stuff>

    logger.info(f"I'm causing an exception! {5 / 0}")

    return func.HttpResponse(
        "Data sent successfuly",
        status_code=200
    )
except Exception:
    logger.exception("Hit an exception at the top level")
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "API - Hit an exception at the top level >_<",
        status_code=500
    )
    sys.exit(1)   <---------------- This line is inaccessible
```

Because I use `return` to send the API response, it also exits out of this function.
The problem is, with Azure Functions, I don't have access to the higher level caller, and if I don't  use `sys.exit(1)`, the function reports that it ran successfully even when it crashes.

Comment: Why can't you print out the error instead of returning?

Comment: Either you can return a response or you can crash the program. You can't do both. Nor am I sure why you would want to.

Comment: Can you expand on "if I don't use sys.exit(1), the function reports that it ran successfully even when it crashes"? I'm not specifically familiar with Azure functions, but I'm wondering *where* this "success" is reported to / what you are doing with that status.

Comment: To answer your questions:

Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/gro7nhj) from the Azure Function dashboard. 

You can see all those invocations are "successful". The only way to turn that symbol into a red "Error" is to use `sys.exit(1)`

It's all the more important because I'm using Grafana to pull logs from my Azure Function and show me the health of my app. In my query, I look for a particular log message that indicates if the function ran successfully or not. If the function fails but reports success, I can't notice the problem.

Comment: Here is an expert of my query to those logs.`

`let og_search = traces`
`| where timestamp between (_start .. _end)`
`| where message has "executed";`
`let success_table = og_search`
`| where message has "succeeded"`
`| summarize success = count() by operation_Name, bin(timestamp, 2h);`


So, to reiterate. If I hit an exception, I'm returning a 500 error code to the user but the function still reports a success, and in my dashboard, it's added to this `count()` of successful iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to return an API response AND fail the program at the same time?

In azure functions, you can do both the things but not at the same time, you can even get failure or an API response and API response comes at the end of the Azure Function, not in the middle or beginning, if you get an API response itself means Function got executed successfully.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


class RithwikCustomException(Exception):
    pass

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        # <do the stuff to get data>

        # Generating a custom exception
        raise RithwikCustomException("Something went wrong Rithwik, Please Check!")

        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Data sent successfully Rithwik",
            status_code=200
        )
    except RithwikCustomException as ex1:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"API - Hit an exception Rithwik: {str(ex1)}",
            status_code=500
        )
    except Exception:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "API - Hit an exception at the top level Man >_<",
            status_code=500
        )
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Functions last executable statement is return, do any thing before return not after that as it will not execute or recognize as a command.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at the trace logs in your second screenshot.

What I need is for that last line to say

"Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Failed)" when we hit an exception and return a 500 status code. Is there any way to do that?

I re-read your comment. It sounds like no. If I had to choose I would prefer using sys.exit(1) to label that run as a failure so I can catch it in the logs. What happens to the caller if the API endpoint doesn't respond. Will it wait for a timeout?

Comment: No, AFAIK there is no way to that, I'll be happier if i am proved wrong and if there is a way.

Comment: @MrPoulet The logs are to check if an Azure Function executed successfully. A function that encountered something wrong and returned a non-2XX response to the caller is the Function executing successfully. The only time the Function should ever outright fail is if something went *very* wrong, and then that should be interpreted as a bug that needs to be fixed. You shouldn't ever _design_ your Function to fail just to return a non-2XX code to the caller, since not only does that reek of code smell, it prevents that instance of the Function from running again without needing to be spun up again.

Comment: @Abion47 the division by zero is just for the purpose of my example, and for testing.

What do you mean by "it prevents that instance of the Function from running again without needing to be spun up again." ?

Comment: @MrPoulet When an Azure Function is invoked for the first time, the virtual machine it runs on gets spun up. This is called the "warm up" process, and after it's done, your code gets run. When a Function completes successfully, its machine is kept up and running for a period of time so that, when the Function is invoked again, your code can be run immediately without waiting for the machine to warm up. If your Function fails, however, the instance is considered to be in a diseased state and is shut down, so the next time the Function gets invoked, you have to wait for it to warm up again.

Comment: @MrPoulet This is only one reason why designing your code around intentional failure like this is a monumentally bad idea. This is likely why Azure Functions don't support returning a response from a failed Function, not just because it's technically difficult to setup a virtual machine to even support that in the first place, but because a user desiring to do so indicates a fundamental flaw in how their Function was architected in the first place.

Comment: @Abion47

Is using sys.exit(1) a bad idea, then? It sounds like using this line to handle failures would still cause the container to be regenerated and therefore generate instability within the app.

Comment: @MrPoulet `sys.exit(1)` by definition forcibly closes the process in a way that tells the OS that it closed abnormally. It should only ever be used if the program is in a deeply diseased state that it cannot possibly recover from. I'm not sure what it will do to an Azure Function, but none of the possibilities I can think of are desirable outcomes. If your end goal is to communicate to the caller of the Function that something wrong happened, just return a response that says so.

Comment: @Abion47 Ok, despite my best efforts I could never find what Microsoft recommends and I never found a doc that explains what you said about restarting containers. I will update my code and see what happens. Thanks